# Python 3: 'multiprocessing' and 'time' module incompatibility?

Tags: python-3.x, time, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I use a `multiprocessing.Pool().imap_unordered(...)` to perform some tasks in parallel and measure the time it takes by calculating the difference of `time.time()` before and after starting the pool tasks.

However, it returns wrong results! When I watch my wall clock while the program runs, it tells me a run time of around 5 seconds. But the program itself outputs a run time of only 0.1 seconds.

I also have a variant of this code without any multiprocessing which takes double the time, but outputs the correct run times.

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    n = int(input("How many grids to create? "))
    use_multiprocessing = None
    while use_multiprocessing is None:
        answer = input("Use multiprocessing to speed things up? (Y/n) ").strip().lower()
        if len(answer) == 1 and answer in "yn":
            use_multiprocessing = True if answer == "y" else False
    t0 = time.time()

    if use_multiprocessing:
        processes = cpu_count()
        worker_pool = Pool(processes)

        print("Creating {} sudokus using {} processes. Please wait...".format(n, processes))
        sudokus = worker_pool.imap_unordered(create_sudoku, range(n), n // processes + 1)

    else:
        progress_bar, progress_bar_length = 0, 10
        sudokus = []

        print("Creating {} sudokus".format(n), end="", flush=True)
        for i in range(n):
            p = int((i / n) * progress_bar_length)
            if p > progress_bar:
                print("." * (p-progress_bar), end="", flush=True)
                progress_bar = p
            new_sudoku = create_sudoku()
            sudokus.append(new_sudoku)

    t = time.time() - t0
    l = len(list(sudokus))
    print("\nSuccessfully created {} grids in {:.6f}s (average {:.3f}ms per grid)!".format(
        l, t, 1000*t/l
    ))
```

And here an example run, which took around 5-6 seconds in reality (after entering the number of grids to create and whether to use multiprocessing, of course):

```
How many grids to create? 100000
Use multiprocessing to speed things up? (Y/n) y
Creating 100000 sudokus using 4 processes. Please wait...

Successfully created 100000 grids in 0.122141s (average 0.001ms per grid)!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Are `multiprocessing` and `time.time()` incompatible? I've heard that `time.clock()` can make problems under these circumstances, but I thought `time.time()` should be safe. Or is there any other problem?**

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

`Pool.imap_unordered(...)` returns a **generator** and no list. That means, its elements are not already created when the method finishes, but only as soon as I access them.

I did this in the line `l = len(list(sudokus))`, where I converted the generator into a list to get the length. And the finish time got measured one line before that, so it correctly reported the time it took to initialize the generator. This was not what I want, so swapping those two lines results in correct times.

I know I may not convert a generator into a list just to find out the length and then discard the list again. I must either rely on the saved requested length if I want a generator, or I must use `Pool.map(...)` instead which produces a list and blocks until it's ready.